# How to add a symbol in a Python user input, also when it's in a created file

Tags: python, user-input, tabulate

I am trying to add a dollar sign ("$") to the users input when it asks about their savings and deposits. At the end of my script I am creating a text file with all the information, but I want the numbers to have the symbol in front of it when the file is created.

```
savings =  int(input("How much money do you have in your savings: ")
deposits = int(input("How much money do you put in deposits: ") 

from tabulate import tabulate
table = tabulate([["Name", "Last", "Age", "Company", "Hourly Rate", "Occupation", "Savings", "Deposits"],
[(name), (last_name), (age), (company), (hourly_rate), (occupation), (savings, + "$"), (deposits)]], headers = "firstrow")
```

I've added + "$" to the savings variable, because I thought that would work but then I would get this error:

```
TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'
```

So in conclusion, I just want it to have the dollar symbol even when the text file is created because this is a sample of what it looks like for now:

Savings Deposits

---

9000     900         <----Missing Dollar Sign

I hope this makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want the `$` to appear in front of the user input?

Comment: `print("${}".format(savings))`

Comment: At the end of my script I am printing it all on a text file on my computer but it still prints out just the numbers I forgot to mention this in my description

Answer (score 3):

See if you'll be using `int` then you cannot concatenate the money along with the dollar sign as '$' is a string.
You can do it like this:

```
# Trying to make it have a special character when file is printed such as "$" Example: $2600
savings = '$' + input("How much money do you have in your savings: ")
deposits = '$' + input("How much money do you put in deposits: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you print the variables, you can type cast them into string and append $  at the start.

```
print("$"+str(savings))
print("$"+str(deposits))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `f-strings`.

If you just want to print with a `$` in front then,

```
savings = int(input("How much money do you have in your savings: "))
deposits = int(input("How much money do you put in deposits: "))

print(f'Savings: ${savings}')
print(f'Deposits: ${deposits}')
```

```
Sample Output:

Savings: $51
Deposits: $25
```

If you want to save the `savings` and `deposits` with a `$` in front, then

```
savings = '$' + input("How much money do you have in your savings: ")
deposits = '$'+ input("How much money do you put in deposits: ")
```

*`savings` and `deposits` will now be strings and not `int`.*

Answer (score 0):

Well it's very easy todo

For Python3 you can simply use `F Strings`

```
savings = int(input("How much money do you have in your savings: "))
deposits = int(input("How much money do you put in deposits: "))
print(f"₹ {savings}")
print(f"₹ {deposits}")
```

Read More About [`F Strings` Here](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `%` sign. 
The % symbol is followed by a character pointing to the data type. If it is an integer, use d.

```
%s -> String
$d -> Int
%f -> Float
```

```py
savings = int(input("How much money do you have in your savings: "))
deposits = int(input("How much money do you put in deposits: "))

savings = "$%d" % savings
deposits = "$%d" % deposits
```